# What Does Electrical Work Represent in Context of Electrochemical Cells?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry

If cell operates reversibly than change in Gibbs energy of system equals electrical work of the cell. As far as I know electrical work is work done by electric field when charge moves between certain potential difference which in case of electrochemical cells is potential difference between two electrodes: $$ W = -zF\Delta E $$

Here work is written per mole of reactant consumed or product formed in electrochemical reaction. It is said when cell is short circuited that cell does no electrical work. How is this possible if charge moves through certain potential difference? What does the fact that there is no load connected to the cell A.K.A cell is short circuited have to do with electrical work since charge will still move between two electrodes or certain potential difference?

Comment: In the case of the ideal short circuit by zero resistance, all spent G energy is converted to thermal energy within the system = cell, as ohmic lose on the internal resistance.

Comment: We are here talking about cell working reversibly which means no loses. Also, it didn't really ask my question.

Comment: @DarioMirić So are you short circuiting the cell with a superconductor? You could also run an electrical heater, using the work to produce heat. The charge moves, but initial and final state are the same (in terms of the wire; of course reactants turn into products and the heat given off).

Comment: @Karsten Theis Here it is important to note that we look at the cell working reversibly, so using superconductors is unneccesary as cell works without losses regardless of conductor used or without joule heating needed in electric heater. Electrical work in electrochemical cell is something different.